# Location Services in iOS 6 not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    static int i=0;
    if([self getCurrentLocation]==nil){
        i++;
        if(i>3){
            [[self locationManager] stopUpdatingLocation];
            useMyLocation = NO;
            [self locationUpdated];
        }
    }else{
        [self locationUpdated];
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)anAlertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
if(buttonIndex==1){
    self.useMyLocation = YES;
    [[self locationManager] startUpdatingLocation];
}else{ // buttonIndex==0
    self.useMyLocation = NO;
    [self locationUpdated];
}
```

}

This is a working code in ios 4 and 5. My problem is that I can't get location to work in ios 6. The app doesn't even asks for permission from the user. After reading around this is what I've tried so far:

- CFBundleDisplayName solution. I already had CFBundleDisplayName in my plist. I tried removing it and adding it again - no go.
- setting the property pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically of Location Manager to NO like this:

...

```
- (CLLocationManager *)locationManager{
        if (locationManager != nil){
            return locationManager;
        }   
        CLLocationManager *tmp = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        tmp.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;  //!@#
        [self setLocationManager:tmp];
        [tmp release];
        [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
        [locationManager setDelegate:self];
        return locationManager;
    }
```

I also read about `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` , I didn't know how to implement it in the code, also i'm not sure if that's the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you ever start the location manager?

```
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: yes, like this: `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)anAlertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
 if(buttonIndex==1){
  self.useMyLocation = YES;
  [[self locationManager] startUpdatingLocation];
 }else{ // buttonIndex==0
  self.useMyLocation = NO;
  [self locationUpdated];
 }
}`

Comment: @Sha, you should update your question to include that - also, does that function ever get called to start the location manager updates?

Comment: In ios lower than 6 - yes. on ios 6 - I have no idea and don't have a device with ios 6 I can debug. Can I test it on the simulator? (that function doesn't get called no matter what version I use of the simulator)

Comment: After some testing i've found that the method above doesn't get called. I'm implemented `[[self locationManager] startUpdatingLocation];` in another place and I can see it fires up but the app still ignores it.

Comment: Did you implement locationManager:didFailWithError: - if so, is it called?

Comment: @Sha when you test on the simulator, are you setting your simulated location? It's off by default. Probably a dumb question, but always good to check.

Comment: The only thing I do to set it on the simulator is to click on the location icon in Xcode and choose a location such as London. Do I need to do any thing else?