# didUpdateToLocation is not called in app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I want to receive location updates. I have added a location delegate to the header file but didUpdateToLocation method not fire my code is

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    UILabel *myLabel;
    CLLocationManager *manager;
    CLGeocoder *geocoder;
    CLPlacemark *placemark;
}
-(void) showCurrentLocation;
@end
```

and .m file like this:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController () 

@end

@implementation FirstViewController


-(id) init
{

    self=[super init];
    if (self) {
        self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor purpleColor];
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;

        [self showCurrentLocation];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void) showCurrentLocation{

    manager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    manager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically=NO;

    geocoder=[[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    manager.delegate=self;
    manager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
}

-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
    NSLog(@"Faild to get location");
}

-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"Location %@",newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentlocation=newLocation;

    if (currentlocation!=nil)
    {
        myLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 200, 200)];
        [myLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Latit %8f",currentlocation.coordinate.latitude]];
        myLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.view addSubview:myLabel];

        [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentlocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemark1 ,NSError *erroe){

            if (erroe==nil && [placemark1 count]>0)
            {
                NSLog(@"Location");
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"error 2 %@",erroe.debugDescription);
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Location Services in iOS 6 not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710591/location-services-in-ios-6-not-working)

Comment: Adding the "location delegate to the header file" just tells the compiler this class intends to implement the specified protocol for _some_ instance of another class expecting that delegate.  In addition to doing what the answer says, make sure init is actually getting called for the VC.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start location manager

```
    manager = [CLLocationManager new];        
    manager.delegate = self;

    [manager startUpdatingLocation]; // forgotten in the code above
```

Also be sure that you setup your scheme properly to simulate location in test mode via Simulator

[image]

Comment: The OP is setting the `delegate`.

Comment: OP? What do you mean? The core of the problem is in absence of startUpdatingLocation

Comment: "OP" - original poster. My point is that you state that the delegate needs to be set. It is set. Your point about calling `startUpdatingLocation` is spot on. Just remove the part about needing to set the delegate since it is already being done.